# Is there a module that allows us to show Python code in a Joomla article?

Tags: module, plugin, extensions, search

I was searching for a module or plugin or an extension in general that allows me to show Python code with the syntax highlighted. I found 2 extensions, namely [Display Code](http://extensions.joomla.org/profile/extension/core-enhancements/coding-a-scripts-integration/display-code) and [Flexi Custom Code](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/core-enhancements/coding-a-scripts-integration/flexi-custom-code), but I guess they do not provide syntax highlighting for Python, am I right?

Is there an extension for Joomla 3 that does exactly I what I want?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you could use [HS Highlighter](http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/hs-highlighter) which support the syntax for Python.

It's free and has fairly good ratings. I would however take note of the last review that was posted regarding Google Webmaster Tools. I do not know if this is true or not, however, it would be something to consider contacting the developer about, just in case page rankings is something that's important to you